# angular ngrx store as identity map

Tags: angular, ngrx, ngrx-store

I have created a simple IdentityMapService and I update the identity map whenever I get data back from my API and map the return value from the identity map back to the data from the API as per the 2 classes below.

```
// identity-map.service.ts
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class IdentityMapService {

  _identityMap = {};

  map(className, object) {
    if (object) {
      var mappedObject;
      if (this._identityMap[className]) {
        mappedObject = this._identityMap[className][object.id];
        if (mappedObject) {
          Object.assign(mappedObject, object);
        } else {
          this._identityMap[className][object.id] = object;
          mappedObject = object;
        }
      } else {
        this._identityMap[className] = {};
        this._identityMap[className][object.id] = object;
        mappedObject = object;
      }
      return mappedObject;
    }
  }

}

// item-api.service.ts
@Injectable()
export class ItemApiService {

  constructor(private api: ApiService, private identityMap: IdentityMapService) {
  }

  getList(page = 1, filter?: any, include?: any) {
    return this.api.get('/items', { page, filter, include })
      .pipe(map(response => {

        response.data = response.data.map(item => {
          return this.identityMap.map('item', item);
        });

        return response;
      }));
  }

  get(id, include?: any) {
    return this.api.get('/items/' + id, { include })
      .pipe(map(response => {

        response.data = this.identityMap.map('item', response.data);

        return response;
      }));
  }

}
```

Is there a way I can achieve this in NGRX? I may have several different views which display  a list items or an individual item in different ways that are all active at the same time and want to make sure that if I update an item in any of the views, it will get updated in all the other views. At this stage I can't think of another way to do the process I am doing which is to get the data when required which updates all other instances of that data.